# React props validation within return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-props, react-proptypes

I'm getting a warning from es-lint telling me that some of my props are missing in props validation, but the problem is that I can't make it work, as it is inside of the return statement.
I have the following code, from which I removed some pieces that weren't important to the matter and would make it unnecessarily large.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const ColumnSearch = () => {
     // few general functions

    return {
        filterDropdown: ({
            confirm,
        }) => (
            <div >
                // some general code for inputs and buttons
            </div>
        ),
        render: text => (
            <Highlighter
                highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
                searchWords={[searchText]}
                autoEscape
                textToHighlight={text}
            />
        ),
    };
};

export default ColumnSearch;
```

es-lint tells me that

```
'confirm' is missing in props validationeslint(react/prop-types)
```

Then, I have tried:

```
ColumnSearch.propTypes = {
    confirm: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

ColumnSearch.propTypes = {
    filterDropdown: PropTypes.shape({
        confirm: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    }).isRequired,
};

filterDropdown.propTypes = {
    confirm: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

But none of them have worked, and the latter tells me:

```
'filterDropdown' is not defined.eslint(no-undef)
```

How can I validate this props? I don't think it would be a good idea to simply use:

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
```

EDIT:

I have created a sandbox with this code:

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-cookies-id7ou)

Comment: How is the component being used?

Comment: It's a search function from ant-design https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-custom-filter-panel
the function getColumnSearchProps 
but it uses a single class component and I'm converting it to stateless component. I also extracted it to an external file called ColumnSearch. I removed the rest of the code as it was just about buttons and generic functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the `confirm` prop, try this.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const ColumnSearch = ({confirm}) => { //declare here
     // few general functions

    return {
        filterDropdown: ({
            confirm,
        }) => (
            <div >
                // some general code for inputs and buttons
            </div>
        ),
        render: text => (
            <Highlighter
                highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
                searchWords={[searchText]}
                autoEscape
                textToHighlight={text}
            />
        ),
    };
};

export default ColumnSearch;

ColumnSearch.propTypes = {
    confirm: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: It didn't work :/
it said: `'confirm' is already declared in the upper scope.eslint(no-shadow)`
So I removed it from the lower scope, and then it just said `confirm is not a function`

Comment: How do you use the component <ColumnSearch confirm=? /> from the parent? You should pass a function to the confirm prop of ColumnSearch

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-cookies-id7ou
That's the code I have and how it's being used. Look for ColumnSearch.jsx, it's where the problem lies. I can't reproduce es-lint error in codesanbox though.